# Unable to install composer-cli

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am unable to npm install -g composer-cli on MacOS 10.12.5.  As Dan pointed out, initially I was using an unsupported version of npm but I installed npm v 3.10.10 which is supported and now I receive the following error message:

As Dan suggested, I installed npm 3.10.10 and tried the install again but it again fails but with a new message:

```
Tims-MacBook-Pro:fabric-tools timolson$ npm install -g composer-cli
Error: Cannot find module 'safe-buffer'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/lib/helpers.js:5:36)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)

    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
npm ERR! Darwin 16.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "composer-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND

npm ERR! Cannot find module 'safe-buffer'
```

I had it installed previously while running HLF v.6 but I am trying to use HLF 1 Beta and saw a note that I needed to be using a version of composer later than 8.0 (I was running version 7.? prior).  So I uninstalled composer-cli and haven't been able to re-install it.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is to avoid confusion for future visitors. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `npm` version 5, which Composer does not yet support. Please try with a supported version of npm. See https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html for the supported operating environment.

Comment: From the stack trace it looks like npm is not installed correctly. We have *many* people using Composer on Mac OS X, so I suspect an install or configuration issue with your machine.

Comment: adding a note for anyone reading this - per https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html  - npm 5.x is supported by Hyperledger Composer

Comment: Apparently, the link is broken.